# (0,1)-matrices with certain properties

Tags: co.combinatorics, reference-request

Fix $r,e >0$.  Let $\mathfrak{B}$ be the set of $(r\times e)$-matrices with entries in $\lbrace 0,1\rbrace$. For $B \in \mathfrak{B}$ and $1 \leq s,t \leq r$, define

$\delta^B_+(t,s) = |\lbrace 1 \leq i \leq e \mid B(t,i)=1 \text{ and } B(s,i)=0\rbrace|,$

$\delta^B_-(t,s) = |\lbrace 1 \leq i \leq e \mid B(t,i)=0 \text{ and } B(s,i)=1\rbrace|,$

and set $\Delta^B(t,s) = \text{Min}\lbrace\delta^B_{+}(t,s),\delta^B_{-}(t,s)\rbrace.$  Define $G(B)$ to be the graph with vertices $1,2,\ldots,r$ which has $\Delta^B(t,s)$ edges between vertices $s$ and $t$.

I would like to classify all $B \in \mathfrak{B}$ such that $G(B)$ is a tree.  I believe I can describe all matrices of this form but I don't yet have a proof.  So I would like to know whether an answer to this question already exists in the literature.  If it does not, I think I can write a proof of my conjecture, but I would prefer not to spend time duplicating (or trying to take credit for) existing results!

Comment: Just to ensure I'm reading you right: $\delta^B_+\left(t,s\right) = \delta^B_-\left(s,t\right)$, correct?

Comment: Are the small deltas sets of indices and the big delta the smallest index?  If so, then the characterization of which B give trees should depend only on the first column of B. Or are you permitting multiple edges between two vertices in a tree?  Gerhard "Ask Me About System Design" Paseman, 2013.04.15

Comment: My apologies - there was a mistake in the original question.  The small deltas should be the size of the sets in question and the large delta the size of the smallest set.  It's now corrected.  (The error crept in when I was trying to work out how to insert brackets.)  

@Darij: Yes, that's correct.  
@Gerhard: Thanks for your comment - I doubt I would have noticed the mistake otherwise.  Hopefully the updated question is harder.  